# What does "plenary intervention" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does "plenary intervention" mean, for example in the following sentence?
The country chose to provide a record of its plenary intervention on the agenda item for the informational annex to the report.

Comment: This is an unusual adjective in the context of an 'intervention'. I am unaware of 'plenary' meaning anything other than full or unlimited. Perhaps you could provide a more detailed context?

Comment: I think it is an intervention that that country did in plenary session, perhaps.

Comment: Yes. It is related to a plenary session. But "intervention" in this context appears to have a special meaning.

Answer (score 1):

It refers to the contribution of the country in a plenary session.

Example
http://www.un.org/esa/forests/pdf/session_documents/unff10/statements/april-9/USRoundtable2.pdf

Answer (score -1):

I think it means general.

**A plenary session was held yesterday.**

Comment: No; please see the dictionary.  *Plenary* means “full”, not “general”.